# Accessing element in corresponding tuple in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

Let's say I have a couple of list of tuples such as:

```
words = [('word1', 2, 4), ('word2', 25, 30)]
texts = [('text1', 0, 15), ('text2', 20, 33), ('text3', 43, 65), ...]`
```

And I want to find the text that a certain word is in. The second element in all the tuples is the start position and the third is the end position.

```
d = {}
for w in words:
    #get the texts that the word is contained in
    d['text'] = [t for t in texts if w[1] >= t[1] and w[2] <= t[2]]
```

I then want to do something like `d['text_start'] = [t[1] for t in d['text']]` to get the start positions corresponding to those texts. Obviously this wouldn't work because each element in `d['text']` is just a string. Is there a way to efficiently access the corresponding elements in the tuple?

Comment: post the expected ouptut and what is the relation b/w `words` and `texts`?

Comment: Save the extra things you want in `d['text']`? You can do `d['text'] = [(t, w[1]) for t in texts if w[1] >= t[1] and w[2] <= t[2]]` and that creates a list of tuples

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That is a thought I have. But there I just want the text -- not the start/end positions.